# Can heat increase cutting power?

Tags: thermodynamics

I'm writing a book in which the protagonist has a sword that she closes in lightning. (It doesn't melt because it is made of a special material.) Could the heat generated by the superhot plasma allow the sword to cutt through metal?

Answer (score 1):

An average lightning bolt is at $30,000 K$ and contains $10^9 J$ of energy and the average sword has a weight of $1.5 kg$. For calculation purposes let us assume that the sword is made of carbon steel which has a specific heat capacity of $490 J/kg K$ and let us also assume that all the energy of the lightning bolt gets transferred to the sword. We can calculate the temperature change of the sword using the equation,

$$Q = mc\Delta T \implies \Delta T = \frac{Q}{mc} = \frac{10^9 J}{490 J/kg K . 1.5 kg} \cong 1.36 \times 10^6 K $$

So your sword (made of special material) should be at a temperature much higher than the melting points of most known metals and contains enough energy to cut through standard metal items.

Comment: Would it be the blade getting hot or the air around it?

Comment: For the superheated air (plasma) to cut through a metal, it must be directed precisely at the point where you want to cut it at and high enough speeds (which I don't see as a possibility here). This will complete an electrical circuit between the sword and the metal, which allows the transfer of energy. Otherwise the heat would be distributed evenly on the surface of the metal. Also, the sword will able to cut through the metal only as fast as the speed of energy transfer between the sword and the metal.

Comment: A sword at 1.3 million degrees would be hot enough to vaporize any material it hit, the person wielding it, and anything else nearby.

Comment: @mmesser314 A sword at 1.3 million degrees would not exist!

Comment: Anyway, how it vaporizes would not depend on its temperature but on its heat capacity and rate of heat transfer.